# Google Sheets - Display Data into another tab if present

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets Tab One I have data.

- Apple | 1 | Eat
- Apple | 2 | Don't Eat
- Banana | 1 | Eat

I want to pull all the data from any rows with "Apple" into another tab.
Tab Two would display:

- Apple | 1 | Eat
- Apple | 2 | Don't Eat

I also want this to work automatically if I add the following row to Tab One:

- Apple | 3 | Eat

So that if Tab One has:

- Apple | 1 | Eat
- Apple | 2 | Don't Eat
- Apple | 3 | Eat
- Banana | 1 | Eat

Tab Two automatically has:

- Apple | 1 | Eat
- Apple | 2 | Don't Eat
- Apple | 3 | Eat

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) on the first cell of the second tab:

```
= QUERY(TabOne!A:C, "select A, B, C where A = 'Apple'")
```